# How to update storage account private endpoint in logic app Application settings

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure logic app already deployed and it refers to the storage account through 'AzureWebJobsStorage' settings. Now, storage account has been moved in VNET and private endpoint is shared with us to connect to storage account.
How to update logic app application settings to refer storage account through private endpoint.
current webjob storage settings look like this : DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=test123;AccountKey=----------;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

We have tried https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/deploying-standard-logic-app-to-storage-account-behind-firewall/ba-p/2626286. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I faced similar issue.

[image]

I could get the desired results following the below steps.

- Firstly, I have integrated VNet in my logic apps.

  [image]
- Then I have added below application settings in my configurations.

  [image]

Below are the network settings in my storage account

[image]

*Note:* This storage account is directly created while creating the logic app standard.

Comment: I have all settings in place except logic app outbound traffic 'VNET Integration'. My logic app is hosted on App service environment which is under subnet. app subnet and storage account subnet has connectivity setup done.  Do I still need to go for logic app outbound traffic 'VNET Integration'? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, Can you check if that works as because it worked only when I enabled outbound traffic